# Error with node_modules while running npm start

Tags: reactjs

I have this error when I type "npm start" in my react application

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! questionnaire@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the questionnaire@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried to remove the folder node_modules and reinstall it with `npm install`, but then the problem reappers. 
What can I do to fix it?

Comment: what about `yarn start`?

Comment: command unrecognized :/

Comment: Where is the additional logging output above?

Comment: well  not recognized cause you dont have yarn installed :) another problem can be from eslint. to mkae sure we need log file report related ot this error and if it is eslint

Comment: I generally recomand install `yarn` and install packages with that

Comment: I would recommend you to remove your node_module and perform npm install.